# awstats "Permission Denied", but file and directories all have permission

Tags: apache2, awstats

I'm getting this notification from awstats:

```
Error while processing /etc/awstats/awstats.conf
Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.conf" by AWStats version 7.4 (build 20150714)
From data in log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log"...
Error: Couldn't open server log file "/var/log/apache2/access.log" : Permission denied
Setup ('/etc/awstats/awstats.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).
```

However, I don't see anything wrong with the permissions:

```
> ls -l /var/log/apache2/access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root adm 62438 Sep 30 09:51 /var/log/apache2/access.log
> ls -ld /var/log/apache2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Sep 30 06:25 /var/log/apache2/
> ls -ld /var/log
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Sep 30 06:25 /var/log/
> ls -ld /var
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Sep 23 14:39 /var/
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT for more clarification:

This error is being thrown by the awstats cron job.  The contents of the cron job are:

```
> cat /etc/cron.d/awstats
MAILTO=root

*/10 * * * * www-data [ -x /usr/share/awstats/tools/update.sh ] && /usr/share/awstats/tools/update.sh

# Generate static reports:
10 03 * * * www-data [ -x /usr/share/awstats/tools/buildstatic.sh ] && /usr/share/awstats/tools/buildstatic.sh
```

So the job is being run by user `www-data`.

`www-data` should have read access to the file; when I run `sudo -u www-data less /var/log/apache2/access.log` it works fine.

Does awstats need write permission to the log file?  It seems weird that it would need it, but I can't find any documentation telling me definitely one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

it's either a :

1. user problem (your process runs as another user than root and the files does not have a 666 or 664)
2. filesystem usage issue (e.g 100% used) FS

Comment: Agreed.  If awstats isn't running as `root` it won't be able to write to this log file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your apache is not running as root:adm and the process wants to write to it ?

Answer (score 0):

check if user www-data has group adm:

root@serverweb:~# id www-data

uid=1001(www-data) gid=1001(www-data) groups=1001(www-data),4(adm)

otherwise add it in /etc/group:

root@serverweb:~# grep www /etc/group

adm:x:4:www-data

www-data:x:33:

Comment: This is an incredibly bad idea.